# node.js - Control a queue of Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, web-crawler

I'm writing a crawler, which will get data from an e-commerce website, using node.js. Each of my input to fetch contains:

- `url`: URL of that link
- `directory`: Directory name into which the output file should be written later
- `page`: Parameter to query

Each page will fetch a number of items, each of them will be fetched in details later

This is my `fetchPage` promise (`agent` is `require('superagent')`) that will fetch HTML text:

```
function fetchPage(url,page){
    return new Promise(
        (resolve,reject)=>{
            if (page>0){
                agent
                .get(url)
                .send('page='+page)
                .end(function(err,res){
                    if (err){
                        reject(err);
                    } else{
                        resolve(res.text);
                    }
                });
            } else{
                agent
                .get(url)
                .end(function(err,res){
                    if (err){
                        reject(err);
                    } else{
                        resolve(res.text);
                    }
                });
            }

        });
}
```

Global calls:

```
var data=[];
for (var i=1;i<=links[0].numOfPages;i++){
    data.push({
        url:links[0].url,
        directory:links[0].directory,
        page:i
    });
}

const promises=data.reduce(
    (promise,data)=>promise.then(()=>{
        fetchPage(data.url,data.page).then(
            (result)=>{
                const urls=getUrls(result);
                Promise.all(urls.map((url,i)=>fetchPage(url,0).then(
                        (result)=>{
                            var item=getItem(result);
                            item.url=url;
                            writeItem(item,data.directory,data.page,i+1);
                        },
                        (error)=>console.log(error)
                )));
            });
    }),
    Promise.resolve());

promises.then((values)=>console.log('All done'));
```

There are 3 functions you will see as utilities (all of them work properly):

- `getUrls`: Process HTML text of a page, returning an array of urls of
  items to crawl in details later
- `getItem`: Process HTML text of an
  item's detailed page, returning an object that will be written into
  file
- `writeItem`: Write an object to file, provided with directory
  and page number to make proper directory and write and store

There is a problem I have been encountering:

- How can I rebuild it    using a queue of promises in which each
  promise will run one-by-one    and one-after-another orderly and
  synchronously and only allows a limited number of promises running concurrently?

How to do it properly and efficiently? How should I change with these current code? I need some demo also

I deleted `fetchItem` function because of its innecessity (actually, it calls `fetchPage` with `page = 0`), now I only utilize `fetchPage`

Comment: You have a classic case of asynchornous action inside of a for loop, see [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486). Use `let page` instead of `var page` as a very simple solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, if you want to really control your execution, then you should not construct a loop to call a promise. It will be executed immediately. Instead, you should construct some data to be supplied to the promise. And sorry, I don't really understand your program flow. I can see that you're calling `fetchPage` and after it completes, calls `fetchItem`, which calls `fetchPage` again. That's maybe why you're getting double callback.

For your second question, here's an example on how you could process each link serially, and process pages in a link in parallel with maximum 3 concurrent jobs.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var chance = new (require('chance'))();

var fetchPage = (url, page) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Simulate Network Operation
    if (page === 0) {
        console.log('Start Downloading: ' + url);
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({
                url: url,
                content: 'Content of ' + url
            });
        }, chance.integer({ min: 10, max: 250 }));
    } else {
        console.log('Start Downloading: ' + url + '?page=' + page);
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({
                url: url + '?page=' + page,
                content: 'Content of ' + url + '?page=' + page
            });
        }, chance.integer({ min: 10, max: 250 }));
    }
});

var fetchItem = link => {
    // Get the data to be supplied to fetchPage promise
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= link.numOfPages; i++) {
        data.push({
            url: link.url,
            page: i
        });
    }
    return data;
};

var writeItem = (item, directory) => {
    // Simulate Writing to Directory
    console.log('Writing ' + item + ' to ' + directory + ' folder');
};

// Make some dummy links
var links = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var domain = chance.domain();
    links.push({
        url: chance.url({ domain: domain }),
        directory: domain,
        numOfPages: chance.integer({ min: 0, max: 5 })
    });
}

// Process each URL serially
Promise.each(links, link => Promise.map(fetchItem(link), data => fetchPage(data.url, data.page).then(result => {
    writeItem(result.content, link.directory);
    console.log('Done Fetching: ' + result.url);
}), {
    // Control the number of concurrent job
    concurrency: 3
})).then(() => {
    console.log('All Done!!');
});
```

**UPDATE:** A simpler example to demonstrate `Promise.each` and `Promise.map`

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var chance = new (require('chance'))();

var tasks = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= chance.integer({ min: 10, max: 20 }); i++) {
    var jobs = [];
    for (var j = 1; j <= chance.integer({ min: 2, max: 10 }); j++) {
        jobs.push({
            job_name: 'Job ' + j
        });
    }

    tasks.push({
        task_name: 'Task ' + i,
        jobs: jobs
    });
}

Promise.each(tasks, task => Promise.map(task.jobs, job => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(task.task_name + ' ' + job.job_name), chance.integer({ min: 20, max: 150 }));
}).then(log => console.log(log)), {
    concurrency: 3
}).then(() => console.log())).then(() => {
    console.log('All Done!!');
});
```

In this example you can clearly see that each task is run sequentially and each job in a task is run in parallel with a maximum of 3 concurrent jobs at a time.

Comment: I deleted `fetchItem` function because of its innecessity (actually, it calls `fetchPage` with `page = 0`), now I only utilize `fetchPage`

And I made some changes but things does not seem to run sequentially

I also edited the question for you to understand my flow better

Comment: If you want to run sequentially, use `Promise.each`. Otherwise, if you want to run concurrently with a limited number of concurrent jobs use `Promise.map` and supply `concurrency` option to the function as demoed in my example above

Comment: About `Promise.each`, let me try, this is new to me. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. Just make sure you're using `bluebird` otherwise you can't use `Promise.each` and `Promise.map`. And try running my example to get a better understanding.

Comment: I'm using `bluebird`. But I'm confused with the difference between `Promise.each` and `Promise.all`. As I understand, `Promise.all` runs an array of promises one-after-another

Comment: Actually not. `Promise.all` runs all promises together. So if you have hundreds of promises then you might be in trouble. Well, Probably I need to provide another example that's simple enough to distinguish the two

Comment: Even if I change `all` into `each` in my above code, it still has trouble. What is still wrong with my above code?

Comment: I added another example. I hope it help you distinguish the two

Answer (score 6):

For your case, I suggest that you install the **[Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird)** Promise library, because it provides a couple of utilities that you can use.

For your questions, Normally, you don't use for loops in conjunction with Promises, you construct an array of data, and a mapping function that returns a Promise, then either `.map() + Promise.all()` or `.reduce()` the array into a single Promise, that resolves when everything has completed.

Bluebird's `Promise.map()` also allows you to specify a concurrency option, that will limit how many actions can run simultaneously.

---

Here are a few examples to get you started:

#### Running async actions concurrently

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const urls = ['https://url1.com', 'https://url2.com', ... ]; // lots of urls
// {concurrency: 4} means only 4 URLs are processed at any given time.
const allPromise = Promise.map(urls, fetchUrlAsync, {concurrency: 4});
allPromise.then(allValues => {
  // Deal with all results in order of original array
});
```

#### Running async actions sequentially:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const urls = ['https://url1.com', 'https://url2.com', ... ]; // lots of urls
// {concurrency: 4} means only 4 URLs are processed at any given time.
const allPromise = urls.reduce((promise, url) => 
  // Start with an empty promise, chain all calls on top of that
  promise.then(() => fetchUrlAsync(url)), Promise.resolve()); 
allPromise.then(allValues => {
  // Deal with all results in order of original array
});
```

---

Try to think of things as collections of values, and the actions you perform on those values, abstract your actions into functions, and call them when appropriate, don't mix fetching with writing in the same place.

Comment: I deleted `fetchItem` function because of its innecessity (actually, it calls `fetchPage` with `page = 0`), now I only utilize `fetchPage`

And I made some changes but things does not seem to run sequentially